# Unable to create boto3 client on AWS EMR pyspark worker (botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, boto3, amazon-emr

I have set up an AWS EMR cluster. I have included this script as the bootstrap script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install needed libraries
sudo pip3 install pandas==1.3.5 awswrangler==2.19.0 boto3==1.26.72
```

When I log into the primary node (using SSH), I am then able to successfully run pyspark:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-167 ~]$ pyspark
```

Then, I am successfully able to import boto3 and connect it to S3, and read in my dataframe (using awswrangler, which uses boto3's credentials under the hood):

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> import awswrangler as wr
>>> src_file = os.environ.get("SRC_FILE")
>>> og_df = wr.s3.read_csv("s3://" + src_file)
>>> og_df.head(3)
```

However, when I submit the spark job...

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-167 ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn \
> --py-files standardize_functions.zip standardize_blocks.py
```

I receive the following error:

```
raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (default) could not be found
```

For reference, below is the code that causes the error only when submitting the spark job on the EMR cluster:

```
import boto3

# Initialize boto3 resource
session = boto3.session.Session()
```

I also receive the same error if I call the boto3 client directly:

```
import boto3

# Initialize boto3 resource
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

Remember, I do **not** receive any errors when running my script inside a pyspark shell on the cluster. Additionally, I do not receive any errors when submitting my script locally (not yarn).

Regarding IAM roles and permissions, here are the permissions set up for my EMR cluster:
[image]

For the first Role "**EMR-can-call-AWS-Services**", here are the permissions attached to that role:

[image]

For the second Role "**EMR-can-call-Services-while-in-cluser**", here are the permissions attached to that role:

[image]

[This link from the Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-sessions) mentions I should be using `session = boto3.session.Session()` when multithreading, but this has failed (see error above).

**UPDATE:** I've followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62463600/how-boto3-find-assume-role-provider?rq=1) to print the IAM role my instance assumes while running in the cluster. So I've added the following code to my .py file:

```
# Temporary code
import requests
r = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info')
print(r.json())
r = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance')
print(r.json())
```

So when I run

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-3-167 ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn \
> --py-files standardize_functions.zip standardize_blocks.py
```

The following is printed before the boto3 error:

```
{'Code': 'Success', 'LastUpdated': '2023-02-22T21:43:49Z', 'InstanceProfileArn': 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:instance-profile/EMR-can-call-Services-while-in-cluser', 'InstanceProfileId': 'XXXXXXX'}

{'Code': 'Success', 'LastUpdated': '2023-02-22T21:44:23Z', 'Type': 'AWS-HMAC', 'AccessKeyId': 'XXXXXX', 'SecretAccessKey': 'XXXXXX', 'Token': 'XXXX', 'Expiration': '2023-02-23T04:03:48Z'}
```

With this, I can verify that my cluster is in fact assuming the correct IAM roles.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I create a boto3 session inside of a pyspark worker on EMR while running a `spark-submit --master yarn` job? How can I access other AWS services while running my python script in a spark job on an EMR cluster?

Comment: So far, I have not been able to create a Boto3 client inside of a pyspark worker inside of an EMR cluster. I have had to access my s3 files a different way, by following this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-input-distributed-cache.html

Comment: Most likely, when you submit the spark job, it's not able to find credentials. I am not familiar with spark, when submit does it run the job in new machine? If that's the case, then pass in then environment variables: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in your spark-submit command. These variables should be available in your shell environment (or aws config file) as you are saying you are able to run boto3 in remote machine.

Comment: By the way, this error usually generates when aws is not configured on the machine (https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cli-config-profile-could-not-be-found)